# how to insert a object into multiple category and retrive using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, multidimensional-array

I have a table having root categories like:

```
fruit
vehicle
goods
```

and sub categories like:

```
fruit   => sweet
        => sour
        => mixed

vehicle => car
        => light vehicle
        => hatch back
        => sedan

goods   => furniture
        => wooden
        => home accessories
```

I want to insert a object into database using multiple subcategory of a root category

```
mango  => fruit(root)   => sour, mixed
maruti => vehicle(root) => car, light vehicle, hatch back
table  => goods(root)   => furniture, wooden, home accessories
```

In my html I have multiple checkbox list of a root category, so how can I insert this into my database and retrieve it in php? 
and my database structure is

```
parentid  cat_id title
0             1   fruit
0             2    vehicle
0             3    goods
1             4    sour
1             5    sweet
1             6    mixed
2             7    sedan
2             8     hatchback
2             9     car
```

and so on

Comment: Do you have related tables in your database already?  Are you sourcing the picklist from the table?  

Show us ya code! :)

Comment: in my databse the structure is like                                                     parent Id, cat id Title
0                 1     fruit
0                 2    vehicle
0                 3    goods

Comment: i have written the databse structure above kindly guide me if i am wrong and how can i achieve my required target @Tim Ogilvy